# using quantmod to retrieve option chain

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to use the quantmod package to download option chain from yahoo finance and would like to filter out, say 5 strike prices near the market price like below:

```
library(quantmod)
baba_option<-getOptionChain("BABA", Exp="2023-06-09")

> baba_option$calls$Strike
 [1]  30  40  45  50  55  60  62  65  67  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76
[18]  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93
[35]  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 105 110 115 120 125 130 135
[52] 140 145 150 155 165 170

baba_price<-84.9

function(x,base){
    base*round(x/base)
}

> ATM_strike<-mround(baba_price,5)
> ATM_strike
[1] 85
```

From here, we get 85 as the at-the-money strike, so next I would like to generate a table showing the prices of call & put options, with strike prices ranging from ATM_strike -5 to ATM_strike+5, which essentially is a table showing options of $80 to $90, given the downloaded expiry date.

```
> baba_option$calls$Vol
 [1]    NA     1     8     1    NA     9     2    15    16     1     1
[12]     2    50     1     1     4     4     3     7    13    62   160
[23]   118   357   427  1397  3858  4711  5238  6328 10880  4037  3227
[34]  4655   987  1675   205    42    41   139    37   712     5    60
[45]     2     1    10     8     1    32     1    NA     1     1     4
[56]    25     1
> baba_option$calls$Last
 [1] 51.90 38.42 42.00 36.72 23.65 21.15 23.35 20.33 18.15 17.65 16.71
[12] 14.00 13.98 11.20 12.23 10.55 10.75  8.96  7.65  7.10  5.25  4.50
[23]  3.60  2.63  2.06  1.48  0.99  0.67  0.44  0.28  0.20  0.11  0.09
[34]  0.06  0.05  0.04  0.03  0.03  0.02  0.03  0.01  0.02  0.03  0.03
[45]  0.01  0.01  0.02  0.02  0.01  0.02  0.01  0.05  0.50  0.04  0.08
[56]  0.01  0.01
> baba_option$puts$Vol
 [1]   40   NA    1    3   NA    5    6    5   NA   NA    6    6    9
[14]    5    5   74    5   22  297   77   44 1605   89  993 1377 1980
[27] 1948  889  446   59   29   40    1    1    1    2    2   12   20
[40]    1    2    5    2    1    1    2    1   NA   NA
> baba_option$puts$Last
 [1]  0.01  0.01  0.03  0.02  0.03  0.08  0.02  0.01  0.05  0.09  0.02
[12]  0.01  0.02  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.02  0.03  0.03  0.04
[23]  0.08  0.16  0.27  0.53  0.87  1.45  2.07  2.81  4.00  3.82  5.30
[34]  6.70  7.90  8.25  8.23  9.70 19.05 11.05 15.97 14.00 17.78 19.34
[45] 24.80 24.75 40.00 46.05 74.65

> call_volume<-baba_option$calls$Vol
> call_price<-baba_option$calls$Last
> strike<-baba_option$calls$Strike
> put_volume<-baba_option$puts$Vol
> put_price<-baba_option$puts$Last
```

And ideally, I would like to know how do I generate a table like the one in picture?

[image: table]

Million thanks for your help, all ideas are very welcome.
By the way, does anyone of you know if the getQuote function in quantmod package no longer working? Cuz I am not able to get the last traded price of a stock using this function.